# recibir como argumento en la linea de comando el nombre de un fichero haciendo re-dirección

Tags: java, archivo, redirección, línea-de-comandos

mi intención es recoger ambos argumentos literales para poder pasarlo al programa de esta manera

```
 java App hola < test.txt
```

según he podido leer solo es posible haciendo uso de **System,in**
no se muy bien como podría lograrlo,ya que mi intención no es leer el fichero solo recoger su nombre para leerlo mas adelante.

De forma que el programa reciba 2 parametros "hola" y "test.txt"

### Main

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
            Foo fo=new Foo();
            fo.do(args[0], new File(args[1]));
            }
    }
```

de esta forma funcionaria perfectamente pero nesecito poder hacerlo con redireccion
como comento arriba.

se agradece las sugerencias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es más de SO que de Java, así que para no liarnos usaré "programa" como ejemplo.

```
programa < test.txt
```

es interpretado por el SO (intérprete de comandos, shell...) de forma que lee el archivo *test.txt* y pasa su contenido como si fuera la entrada estándar del programa. El programa no sabe de dónde le vienen los datos, para él es como si el texto lo escribieras por teclado (que es la entrada estándar por defecto).

Lo que tienes que hacer es

```
programa test.txt
```

Aquí no hay redirección y se pasa *test.txt* como argumento al programa.

De hecho con

```
java App hola < test.txt
```

el programa *java* recibe los argumentos "App" y "hola", lanza el JVM e invoca al pasa al *main* de "App", y pasa al *main* los argumentos que no se usan para configurar la JVM (en este caso solo "hola").

La solución es

```
java App hola test.txt
```

Comment: como comento arriba esa es la solución,que utilizo y funciona,pero quería este formato de entrada con la redireccion  java App hola < test.txt  como comento para poder hacer una redirecion es utilizando System.in,pero no se como llevarlo al programa,en realidad el fichero no lo necesito leer en ese momento sino mas adelante solo necesito su nombre.

Comment: Y como te he respondido, con la redirección el proceso no sabe de dónde le viene la entrada. Así que con la redirección NO vas a obtener el nombre del fichero.

Comment: vale te entiendo,no es posible trampearlo de alguna forma en el main? pregunto..

Comment: Es el Sistema Operativo el que hace esto. No es posible.